# How to shift part of a string with regex

Tags: regex

I have a huge text file. 
I need to change this:

```
someChars_getSomeCharsValue(
```

to this:

```
someChars_getValueSomeChars(
```

You can see the pattern. What I need is to shift `Value` (which stands right before the open parenthesis) right after `get`.

There are no white-spaces in the text. `someChars` stands for a string with ASCII chars and undefined length.

This is an excerpt of a C header file where I need to change macro definitions. This is an excerpt from the file:

```
#define usart_getLeastSignificatntBitFirstValue()   ( __usart_getPropertyValue(0, 10) )
```

to turn into this:

```
#define usart_getValueLeastSignificatntBitFirst()   ( __usart_getValueProperty(0, 10) )
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote

Comment: you want to find a function using \w*?get(\w*?)\( then split the group using upper case letters and move the last such element to the first?

Comment: what language are you using to do this??

Comment: This one https://regex101.com/

Comment: Sounds great. Can you give me  an example.

Comment: you mean you want it in php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124301/discussion-between-rakesh-g-r-and-hairi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should get you what you need in php...in other languages too the idea is the same:

```
<?php
$re = "/(\\w*?get)(\\w*?)(\\()/"; 
$str = "#define usart_getLeastSignificatntBitFirstValue()   ( __usart_getPropertyValue(0, 10) )"; 

$result2=preg_replace_callback($re,function($groups){
    $words=preg_split("/(?=[A-Z])/",$groups[2],-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $newStr='';
    for($i=0;$i<count($words);$i++)
    {
        if($i==(count($words)-1))
            $newStr=$words[$i].$newStr;
        else
            $newStr=$newStr.$words[$i];
    }
    return $groups[1].$newStr.$groups[3];
},$str,-1);
echo '<br>';
echo $result2;
?>
```

Try the code somewhere like http://phpfiddle.org/